# Higher order derivative of a composition of vector valued multivariate functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

I have this composition of twice differentiable functions :
$$ \Bbb R ^m \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb R^n \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb R^k$$
And I'm trying to get this result from a book :
$$ (g \circ f)''(x) (h,k) = (g''\circ f')(x)\big(f'(x)h,f'(x)k\big) + (g'\circ f)(x)\big(f''(x)(h,k)\big) $$
A poor attempt :
$$ 
\begin{align}
(g \circ f)^{\prime\prime}(x) (h,k)
  & = \bigg(\big((g' \circ f)(x) f'(x)\big)(h)\bigg)'(k) \\
  & = \big((g' \circ f)(x)\big)'(k) f'(x)(h) + (g' \circ f)(x)\big(f''(x)(h,k)\big) \\
  & = (g'' \circ f)(x)f'(x)(k) f'(x)(h) + (g' \circ f)(x)\big(f''(x)(h,k)\big) \\
& = (g''\circ f \space)(x)\big(f'(x)k,f'(x)h\big) + (g' \circ f)(x)\big(f''(x)(h,k)\big) \\
 (?) & = (g''\circ f')(x)\big(f'(x)h,f'(x)k\big) + (g'\circ f)(x)\big(f''(x)(h,k)\big)
\end{align}$$
So It feels like it follows the rules of bilinear differentiation but then $h$ and $k$ should swap places and there's that extra $f'$. What am I doing wrong.